# Upstart script for New Relic monitoring plugin

Tags: newrelic, upstart, newrelic-platform, start-stop-daemon

I am trying to start a New Relic monitoring plugin [`MeetMe/newrelic_plugin_agent`](https://github.com/MeetMe/newrelic-plugin-agent/) with upstart on Ubuntu 12.04. Here is the script I wrote:

```
env USER=newrelic
env DAEMON="/usr/local/bin/newrelic_plugin_agent"
env DAEMONARGS=" -c /etc/newrelic/newrelic_plugin_agent.cfg"

start on startup
stop on shutdown

exec start-stop-daemon --start --chuid $USER --exec $DAEMON --$DAEMONARGS
```

The following error is written to the corresponding upstart log: `Error starting /usr/local/bin/newrelic_plugin_agent: Cannot write to specified pid file path /var/run/newrelic/newrelic_plugin_agent.pid`

If I add `--make-pidfile --pidfile /var/run/newrelic/newrelic_plugin_agent.pid` parameters to `start-stop-daemon`:

```
exec start-stop-daemon --start --make-pidfile --pidfile
/var/run/newrelic/newrelic_plugin_agent.pid --chuid $USER
--exec $DAEMON --$DAEMONARGS
```

the log contains `start-stop-daemon: unable to open pidfile '/var/run/newrelic/newrelic_plugin_agent.pid' for writing (No such file or directory)`.

`/var/run/newrelic/` folder exists and is owned by `newrelic` user and is assigned to `new relic` group.

How do I write the upstart script, so that the newrelic_plugin_agent is started in boot?

Comment: With upstart you don't have to use things like `start-stop-daemon`. Just set `exec` to start the process and upstart takes care of the rest.

Comment: The same problem if using exec. But I found a solution (see below)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not managed to start the New Relic plugin by using upstart, but there was a much simpler way to have it startet on boot. The Plugin also contains init.d scripts for RedHat and Ubuntu ([here](https://github.com/MeetMe/newrelic-plugin-agent/tree/master/etc/init.d)). So just

1. Copy `/opt/newrelic_plugin_agent/newrelic_plugin_agent.deb` in `/etc/init.d` folder: `cp /opt/newrelic_plugin_agent/newrelic_plugin_agent.deb /etc/init.d/newrelic_plugin_agent`
2. Make the copied script executable: `sudo chmod a+x /etc/init.d/newrelic_plugin_agent`
3. Configure this script to run on system boot: `update-rc.d newrelic_plugin_agent defaults`
4. Start the script: `/etc/init.d/newrelic_plugin_agent start`

Comment: A symlink instead of a copy will make an upgrade easier.

Comment: I am not quite sure it will completely solve the problem - the original init.d script is not executable and one cannot run chmod on a symlinc. The update will overwrite the original script making it non-executable and the symlink will stop working.

Comment: Hm, OK. Of course the original script *should* be executable if things were done right. But then again the installer *should* take care of everything for you. File a bug with the vendor!